# Approximation Algorithm for TSP-like problem

Tags: approximation-algorithms, optimization, tsp

Suppose we are given a graph with distances for each of the edges and merit for each of the nodes. What are the best (approximation) algorithms for computing the the most meritorious simple path with a cap on the maximum distance allowed?

Comment: Related: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/25922/2150

Comment: Orienteering refers to the problem where one wants a walk with a given budget instead of a simple path - a node is allowed to be visited more than once but the merit/profit is only counted once. If distances satisfy triangle inequality then asking for a simple path is equivalent to asking for a walk. However, if you insist on a simple path then what you are looking for is closely related to the longest path problem. For longest paths check Gabow's paper and pointers: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539704445366?journalCode=smjcat